# Eliminate duplicate code in C# catch

Tags: c#, entity-framework

My C#6, .Net 4.6, Entity Framework 6 application has lots of methods on this basic pattern:

```
try
{
    using (Entities dbContext = new Entities())
    {
        // Some database stuff
    }
}
catch (System.Data.Entity.Core.EntityException eEntCore)
{
    // May occur if connection to DB fails
    throw MyApplicationException("Cannot access data store (Entity Core Exception)", eEntCore);
}
catch (System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.DbUpdateException eDbu)
{
    throw MyApplicationException("Cannot access data store (Database Exception)", eDbu);
}
catch (System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException eSql)
{
    // Usually occurs after a Referential Integrity error
    throw MyApplicationException("Cannot access data store (Data Exception)", eSql);
}
```

These exceptions are those that I have discovered so far – there may be more.

My problem is that, if another exception type shows up, I have to amend dozens of methods to add the new exception. I have tried to centralise the error processing with this catch block:

```
catch (Exception e)
{
    AnalyseException(e);
}
```

where AnalyseException() does the work; it throws either  MyApplicationException or the original (unknown) exception. The design works except the stack trace is not preserved (and it commits the grave sin of catching Exception).

The user interface handles MyApplicationException. I don’t want to make it handle all the different EF and SQL exception types.

I have tried to rework the design with this C#6 feature:

```
catch (Exception ex) when (AnalyseException(ex))
```

but I can’t get that to preserve the stack trace. Is there a way to preserve the stack trace without lots of duplicated code?

Comment: Why are you catching exceptions at all? That looks like the fatal flaw.

Comment: I believe this has to do with stack-trace behavior and throwing exceptions. Read the Remarks section on this page (https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.exception.stacktrace(v=vs.110).aspx). "If the exception is thrown, and later rethrown, in the same method, the stack trace only contains the location where the exception was rethrown and does not include the location where the exception was originally thrown."

Comment: Although I fully agree with Chris and Daniel's answers, there is a huge difference between `throw ex;` and `throw;` insider a `catch` block. The former blows away your stack trace. The latter re-throws the caught exception and preserves the stack trace. Also, you're creating new exception instances and including the caught exception as an inner exception. That inner exception will include the original stack trace.

Answer (score 3):

I think you have two problems here:

1. You're catching exceptions just to wrap them up in your own exception type. Why bother?
2. You have to modify "dozens of places" if you try to catch a new exception. This means you have a leaky abstraction and you're repeating your data access code.

The best solution is to not bother wrapping the exception. Catch exceptions when you can do something useful with it.

The second best solution is to keep your exception handling the same (it looks fine to me, honestly) and encapsulate your data access logic behind an appropriate interface.

Answer (score 1):

You're just flatly handling exceptions you should not be handling. You should only handle exceptions that you can recover from. There is no recovery from those exceptions. They will not succeed by retrying the request.

You should not catch those exceptions. You should allow them to bubble the whole way up the stack. At the very top of the stack your global exceptional handling should trap these unhandled exceptions, log them, and communicate a generic server response to the client.

Answer (score 0):

Following best practice, you should have a general exception block where you catch `Exception`. In the catch block you should log an error message if needed and then call `throw;`. This will allow the exception to bubble up and show a more useful error message to the user.

Answer (score 0):

I suppose this could work:

```
try
{
    using (Entities dbContext = new Entities())
    {
        // Some database stuff
    }
}
catch (Exception ex)
{
   if (!(ex is System.Data.Entity.Core.EntityException || ex is System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.DbUpdateException || ex is System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException))
         throw;

      throw new MyApplicationException("Cannot access data store (" + ex.GetType().ToString() + ")", ex)
}
```

Preserving the stack trace is not possible unless you use "throw" (without wrapping it into your kind of exception). throw marks the place for the stack trace, so you either throw the original exception and catch it somewhere else or you leave it that way.